# Crear imagen binaria de contornos con 0s y 1s en vez de True y False en Python

Tags: python, opencv, booleano

Estoy intentando generar una imagen binaria de contornos. Para ello creo una plantilla de tal forma que la imagen sería:

`imbin = Gmag > U` donde Gmag es la magnitud del gradiente de la imagen y U un determinado umbral que saco.

El problema es que quiero visualizar dicha imagen pero no puedo al ser todos los elementos True o False y me gustaría que dichos elementos fueran 0s y 1s pero sin que la imagen dejara de ser de tipo bool.

Para visualizar utilizo el método de OpenCV `cv.imshow("título", imbin).`

Comment: `int(True)` devuelve 1 y con `False` devuelve 0. Solo convierte a entero la representación booleana

Comment: Pero busco aplicarlo a imbin, imbin es una matriz que tiene las dimensiones de la imagen y está rellena de True y False, de tipo bool. ¿Cómo lo aplicaría ala matriz?

Comment: Si por lo menos colocarás cual es la matriz te podria dar una respuesta

Comment: haces una matriz nueva, si usas numpy es simple: nueva=imbin.astype("int32") siendo imbin un array.

Comment: Al momento de crear tu pregunta debes de proporcionar un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Christian, la matriz imbin es de 800x600 y está repleta de True y False en cada celda, por tanto si hago imbin[245, 499] me devolvería bien o True o bien False. Y necesito que en vez de eso me devuelva o bien o un 0 o un 1

Comment: Utiliza una comprensión de lista anidada, en un momento te doy una respuesta

Comment: @Zyder. No des explicacones en los comentarios; edita tu pregunta para agregar esa información relevante. Además, el código tienes que mostrarlo; simplemente "hablar" de él no es suficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Conseguido con `nueva=imbin.astype("int32")`

Comment: lo que te dije en mi comentario anterior

Comment: sii, quería responderte pero no sabía donde era, ¡muchas gracias!